# Create a task in a change request via the service now API?

Tags: api, servicenow

Does anyone know if it's possible to create individual tasks in a change request via the ServiceNow API?  I see where I can create a change itself, but struggling with creating individual tasks in said change request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request:

```
POST https://my_instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/change_task
```

Body:

```
{"change_request":"{CHANGE_SYS_ID}","short_description":"Short description goes here","description":"Description goes here"}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked great.